# Mi Calendario se tapa por la barra superior

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo el siguiente diseño

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y como pueden ver el calendario de **DatePicker** lo tapa la barra que tengo en la parte superior.

Codigo de la  funcion del Calendario

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var date_input=$('input[name="date_inicio"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
  var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  date_input.datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
  })
})
```

Podrian ayudarme a que se muestre completo.

Gracias.

Comment: Mira a ver cuales son sus `z-index` y haz que el del calendario sea superior

Comment: Hola no entendi, podrias ayudarme con mas referencias.

Comment: ¿Usas solo bootstrap o también tienes estilos propios? Si también has añadido estilos comparte la parte de tu css en la que das estilos al calendario. Un problema en la posición de un elemento lo normal es que sea por css y no por javascript.

Comment: estan los estilos de la plantilla pero tambien uso bootstrap pero el calendario lo saque con bootstrap-datepicker.min.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes especificar la direccion hacia donde se va abrir el calendario usando la propiedad `orientation`.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var date_input=$('input[name="date_inicio"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
  var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  date_input.datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: "bottom"
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<input name="date_inicio"></input>
```